# Unknown or bad timezone () in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

code:

```
public function attendance()
{
    $company = admin()->company;
    if ($company->office_start_time != NULL && $company->office_end_time != NULL) {
        $this->officeStartTime = $company->getOfficeStartTime()->timezone($company->timezone)->format('g:i A');
        $this->officeEndTime = $company->getOfficeEndTime()->timezone($company->timezone)->format('g:i A');
    }
    return \View::make('admin.company_settings.attendance', $this->data);
}
```

Model: company.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use App\Observers\CompanyObserver;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
class Company extends \Eloquent
{
    use Billable;
    protected $fillable = ['company_name','contact','address','name','email','country','timezone','logo','locale','billing_address','currency','currency_symbol'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'last_login', 'trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at', 'licence_expire_on'];
    protected $appends = ['logo_image_url'];

    public function getTimezoneAttribute($value)
    {
        return explode("=", $value)[0];
    }

    public function getTimezoneIndexAttribute()
    {
        return explode("=", $this->attributes["timezone"])[1];
    }

    public function getOfficeEndTime(Carbon $date = null)
    {
        if ($date == null) {
            $date = Carbon::now();
        }
        $dateStr = $date->format("Y-m-d");
        $end = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateStr . " " . $this->attributes["office_end_time"]);
        $start = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateStr . " " . $this->attributes["office_start_time"]);
        if ($end < $start) {
            $end->addDay();
        }
        return $end;
    }
    public function getOfficeStartTime(Carbon $date = null)
    {
        if ($date == null) {
            $date = Carbon::now();
        }
        $dateStr = $date->format("Y-m-d");
        $start = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateStr . " " . $this->attributes["office_start_time"]);
        return $start;
    }
}
```

I am new in laravel I have got `InvalidArgumentException Unknown or bad timezone ()` in carbon.php I have got `throw new InvalidArgumentException('Unknown or bad timezone ('.$object.')');`. I had already set `timezone` in `config/app.php`. Once I click on tab then I got this issue I don't have any idea about this. So, How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: what is the value of `$company->timezone`?

Comment: it show nothing  `"timezone": ""` @lagbox

Comment: that doesn't sound like a valid timezone

Comment: how can I create valid timezone @lagbox

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the line below

```
$this->officeStartTime = $company->getOfficeStartTime()->timezone($company->timezone)->format('g:i A');
```

`$company->timezone` company's timezone **is not set** or **wrong value is set**
also

```
$this->officeStartTime = $company->getOfficeStartTime()->timezone($company->timezone!=''?$company->timezone:'somehardcodedtimezone')->format('g:i A');
```

Comment: How can we set `$company->timezone` @phpdroid

Comment: you must be having Company Model table where you must have this field, maybe in company's setting

Comment: Use a dd($company->timezone) in line before. This stop execution and show value inside () @Klint

Comment: If empty is not set.... also response of @phpdroid is correct. You must see why your model **company** has a null or empty value in field timezone...